# additional space between css classes in html markup

Tags: html, css

what is the difference between this

```
<p class="class1 class2"></p>
```

and this

```
<p class="class1  class2"></p>
```

the second has an extra space between the classes. both are working fine.

but, will it create any problem while working with javascript or jquery etc?

Comment: I don't think it would create any problem. But, why do you want to put two spaces in between? Check this out:- https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it make a difference? This is not really a valid question without trying it and making the effort yourself

Comment: I tried that and that works fine. My question is will it create problem anywhere while working with jquery or javascript etc @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Just paste above code in any HTML editor, and apply styles or scripts, you will get your answer, PS: HTML ignores extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HTML accepts one space only and converts more than one space to one space. So when you write:

```
<p class="class1 class2"></p>
```

it's equal to:

```
<p class="class1   class2"></p>
```

***Note***:However better way is use one space.

```css
.c1.c2 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1               c2">I have more than one space.(We have same style)</div>
<div class="c1 c2">I have one space.(We have same style)</div>
```

Comment: thanks. so accessing and modifying from javascript or jquery won't create any problem rite?

Answer (score 3):

Having spaces in classes like that should never make a difference, for the exception that some HTML validator might get picky about it. Naturally though, you should try to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference, in this case.

```css
.test {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test test2">
Hello world
</div>
<div class="test  test2">
Hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any issue, both are completely valid. But I don't think there is any need to put multiple spaces if they don't make any difference, even doing that will make your code look ugly. If you make this practice your habit, any professional developer won't be impressed from you after looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

As per w3 standard, this is not an issue

[HTML Validator response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVptx.png)

Answer (score 1):

No it never create problem, But spaces use memory spaces in code.

But it you are performing manipulation of class string, It cause problem 100%.

Comment: thanks. I don't know much about manipulation of class string where can I get a good overview about that

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp - For Javascript String Manipulation..and https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_string.asp - For PHP String Manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be a difference. Consider this scenario: Only the text of the second paragraph will be colored red.

```css
[class="class1  class2"] { color:red }
```

```html
<p class="class1 class2">One space</p>
<p class="class1  class2">Two spaces</p>
```

Worth bearing in mind when you read nonsense like "HTML ignores extra spaces." (It doesn't) and "Have you tried it?" (How do you know you've covered all scenarios?)

Answer (score 0):

Just as for text, Html ignores duplicate spaces.

If you try to inspect it, it will show the spaces (so as for text) – but your browser should be able to ignore.

Therefore – there is no difference between the two!

Look:

```css
  .class1 {
    color : red;
  }

  .class2 {
    color : blue;
  }
```

```html
   

  <html>
    <body> 
      <p class="class1  class2">ffff       ff</p>
      <p class="class1 class2">ffff ff</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```